# Can you use live share between Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, vscode-liveshare, visual-studio-liveshare

I would like to host a Live Share session from Visual Studio 2019.

The person I want to host it to hasn't got Visual Studio 2019, but Visual Studio Code.

**Can he join my Live Share session?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/live-share-feature-in-visual-studio-2019-and-visual-studio-code/) someone shows that it works from Visual Studio to VS Code.